# Xcode is acting crazy, duplicating lines and scrolling by itself

Tags: xcode, duplicates, lines, behavior

I know it's been already asked 9 month ago, but there hasn't been answers since and I can not comment.
So it's been 1 year and a half, I'm on Xcode 7.2 now, I changed of project, I ended up buying a new MacBook, and I still have the same bug showing up from time to time and ruining a day of work... At each key typed, Xcode is acting crazy and scroll my source, highlight, show duplicate lines... A visual bug I guess. (I made a video of it, it looks funny) I guess I can ask Apple who will tell me to reinstall everything from scratch again, and it will come back again after a few weeks... If anyone has just even seen that, please let me know!

Comment: I've only ever seen that on betas and it was never that bad.  I don't know what to suggest given you're on a different Mac and getting the same symptoms.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue on Xcode 8.2.1 ‍♂️

Comment: @Fantattitude glad to know I was not crazy... My Xcode 8.0 on 10.12.2 is good know, then when I start on my previous partition, still the same.